# Why is the blank-tape halting problem $H_0$ so relevant in literature?

Tags: computer-science, computability, turing-machines, decidability

After comparing some text books and lectures about computability theory I encountered not only the halting problem
$$H = \{\langle M,x \rangle \mid \text{the Turing machine $M$ halts on input $x$}\}$$
but also the blank-tape halting problem
$$H_0 = \{\langle M \rangle \mid \text{the Turing machine $M$ halts on input $\varepsilon$}\}.$$
Here, $\varepsilon$ denotes the empty word.

I know that $H_0$ is as undecidable as $H$ is, since they can both be reduced to each other, but I also know that any reduction from $H_0$ (e.g. the one from the proof of Rice's theorem) could also be done from $H$. What intrigues me is why so many authors first introduce $H_0$ and then use it in their reductions instead of just using $H$. I do not think the proofs become significantly simpler.

My guess is that it has an historical reason but I cannot find where $H_0$ was introduced the first time.

Comment: Could have didactical reasons : The busy beaver function (which is related to $H_0$) is a good introduction to turing machines.

Comment: I don't know for certain but here's a couple of ideas: in Turing's original work, the "sequence computed by a machine" is the sequence of symbols printed by a machine that starts with a blank tape. Also, studying $H_0$ may help the intuition and kind of simplifies the argument as you don't need to worry about the input.